# Whether an Enterprise/Company can use Dialog flow standard edition

Tags: dialogflow-es

We are looking at dialogflow for one of our chatbots which won't get much of visitors so whether there is any restrictions on dialogflow chatbot being used by Enterprises (I hope it's not)

Answer (score 0):

If your requirements satisfied with the Standard edition then there are no restrictions to use it for your organization from the Google.

You check your requirements lie in the which editions [here](https://dialogflow.com/pricing)